# merging subarrays of multidimensional arrays while sorting array alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

Trying to alphabetically merge arrays with foreach loop.

```
<?php
$fruits = array(
    'Apple' => array('ids'=>array(1,2)),
    'Banana' => array('ids'=>array(3,4)),
    'Ananas' => array('ids'=>array(5,6))
    );

$result = array();

foreach ($fruits as $name=>$subarr) {
    $first_letter = mb_substr($name, 0, 1);

    $result[$first_letter] = $subarr;
}
```

print_r($result);
gives me smth like

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 6
                )
        )
```

```
[B] => Array
    (
        [ids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
                [1] => 4
            )
    )
```

)
 instead of smth like

```
    [A] => Array
        (
            [ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 6
                )
        )
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain why you expected this array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite your result every iteration in this line:

```
$result[$first_letter] = $subarr;
```

Just create a new array if the subArray in the result array doesn't exists and merge the `ids` subArray into your result array.

```
foreach ($fruits as $name=>$subarr) {
    $first_letter = mb_substr($name, 0, 1);

    if(!isset($result[$first_letter]))
        $result[$first_letter] = [];
    $result[$first_letter] = array_merge($result[$first_letter], $subarr["ids"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use foreach loop.

```
$fruits = array(
    'Apple' => array('ids'=>array(1,2)),
    'Banana' => array('ids'=>array(3,4)),
    'Ananas' => array('ids'=>array(5,6))
    );

$result = array();
foreach ($fruits as $name=>$subarr) {
    $first_letter = mb_substr($name, 0, 1);
    foreach($subarr as $key=>$value){
        foreach ($value as $gkey => $gvalue) {
            $result[$first_letter]['ids'][] = $gvalue;
        }

    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Display above code output like below.

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 6
                )

        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```